# Do Kanji characters ever have different pronunciations in Kansaiben?

Tags: words, names

Do Kanji characters ever have different pronunciations when Kansaiben is used?

Comment: Do you happen to mean _reading_, as in the same character is read differently between the different dialects in the same context/sentence?

Comment: Yeah, the use of "kanji" rather than "words" made me think JACK meant readings as well.

Comment: 鮭 「シャケ」「サケ」とかかなぁ・・？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean, does Kansaiben use different intonation (pitch) for words that are often represented by kanji characters, the answer is yes.
Well known ones with differences (with and without kanji) are: 飴(あめ-flat pitch), 雨（あめ{LH}) and 橋(はし{hl}), 箸(はし{LH}), 日本(にほん{HLL}), 二本(にほん{LLH}), こんにちは{LHLLH}, ありがとう{LLLHL}, etc.

To summarize, kanji is not relevant to the intonation (pitch accent). A rough equivalent would be an American southerner pronouncing 'wash' differently from a northerner. The spelling does not dictate the pronunciation (except in cases where the spelling is intentionally changed to reflect accent).

As it appears that you are talking about words like 違う, which are pronounced differently in Kansai (and involve kanji), [here's a link](https://kansai-ben.com/2017/09/23/%E9%96%A2%E8%A5%BF%E5%BC%81%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%86%E3%81%9F%E3%80%81%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%81%9F%E3%80%81%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%86%E3%81%9F/) with a few similar examples.

Comment: I just thought of 違う, which actually is pronounced differently in Kansai (ちがう vs. ちゃう). Maybe that's what you mean?

Comment: thats exactly what I mean.